# Adding a promise to a Google Maps API call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to return an array from a function in Javascript/jQuery but the function is returning before the array has been set (as it is an AJAX call).

I have been advised to use a promise but I have not used these before and have so far been unable to implement this into my code. Here is my code:

```
mapClass.setLatLng = function(location, clubs) {        
        document.geoCodeRequestCompleteFlag = 0;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();      
        geocoder.geocode({'address' : location}, function(results, status) {    
            //console.log(results);
            if(status === "OK") {                   
                var latLngArray = [];
                latLngArray.push(parseFloat(results[0].geometry.location.lat()));
                latLngArray.push(parseFloat(results[0].geometry.location.lng()));   
                var sortedArray = mapClass.calculateDistances(clubs, latLngArray);  
                return sortedArray;
            }           
        });             
    }
```

As you can see, the sortedArray variable is empty when I return is. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could add blocking code into this to ensure the array variables are set before returning?
Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The way you use promises is that you create a promise and then return that promise from your method. This promise has methods like `.then(successHandler, errorHandler)` that enable you to specify functions to execute when the promise is *resolved* (is given a value). You then resolve the promise when you get back the results from the geocoder call at some point in the future.

In jQuery, the promises are called [Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Your code would then change to something like this:

```
mapClass.setLatLng = function(location, clubs) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred(),
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        document.geoCodeRequestCompleteFlag = 0;
        geocoder.geocode({'address' : location}, function(results, status) {    

        if (status === 'OK') {                   
           var latLngArray = [
              +results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
              +results[0].geometry.location.lng()
           ];

           deferred.resolve(mapClass.calculateDistances(clubs, latLngArray));
         } else {
           deferred.reject(status);
         }          
     });             

     return deferred.promise();
}
```

You would use it like so:

```
mapClass.setLatLng('123 Some St, Wherever', [/* clubs */])
 .then(function (sortedArray) {
    console.log('Promise resolved with: ', sortedArray);
}, function (err) {
    console.error('Uh oh! An error occurred!', err);
});
```

Comment: Fantastic answer and explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

Update: The module is deprecated, use @googlemaps/google-maps-services-js instead.

---

If you are using the official [Google Maps Official NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google/maps), You can do it much easier and cleaner.

First, you need to initialize the client with a `Promise` property:

```
const googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
  key: 'your API key here',
  Promise: Promise
});
```

Then, all you need to do is to use `asPromised()` and after that you are good to go:

```
googleMapsClient.geocode({
  address: '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA'
})
.asPromise()
.then(response =>  response.json.results)
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: is there any documentation for module support of promises? i'm trying to do this myself and it doesn't return a response

Comment: Be careful though - this NPM module is intended for server-side API requests and only works with a *server key*. It's not intended for XHR requests.

Comment: What is the source of the `Promise` parameter in the client initialization?! It does not appear in the documentation!